# ASP.NET model won't load my repository

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I try to load my repository into my view like this

```
@model BlueRateITRepositories.Repository.FilmRepository;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Films";
}

<h2>Films</h2>
```

The model gives the error "'FilmRepository' is a type which is not valid in the given context"

Controller code

```
FilmRepository FilmRepository = new FilmRepository();

// GET: Film
public ActionResult Films()
{
    return View(FilmRepository);
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: try renaming your object to lowercase `FilmRepository filmRepository = new FilmRepository();` and pass that to the view.  `return View(filmRepository);`

Comment: Should I change anything in the view then as well, it didn't work just like that

Comment: No change needed in view.

Comment: It is still giving me the same error though

Comment: Why in the world are you passing an entire repository to your view? That's a complete and total violation of the MVC pattern. Query what you need in your controller, and then pass only the simple model to your view.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks Chris Pratt, I wasn't aware of this. I'm still a student.

Comment: Take some time to familiarize yourself with the MVC pattern, in general. Your View should have as little logic as possible, and preferably none. The Model should contain all the business logic, while the Controller should wire the Model to the View. Also pay attention to how applications are typically built on the ASP.NET MVC framework. If no one ever does something you are doing in any sample application, that's a pretty clear indication that you should give what you're doing a close look and determine if you should actually be doing that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I've got a bad habbit of putting too much code in my UILayers instead of my logic layers, I'm currently working on it though! thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of your model declaration.And also, as suggested by @shyju , try keeping the object name in a different casing than the class name.

Model declaration should be-

```
<namespace>.ClassName
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Glad it worked. But as Chris Pratt and Mason mentioned, do it the right way. You already got that. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this wrong. You should not pass a repository class to your view. Views should accept the information they need and display it.

Change your controller:

```
FilmRepository filmRepository = new FilmRepository();

public ActionResult Films()
{
    List<Film> films = filmRepository.GetFilms();
    return View(films);
}
```

Your view should then display the films:

```
@model IEnumerable<BlueRateITRepositories.Models.Film>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Films";
}

<h2>Films</h2>
@foreach(var film in Model)
{
    <p>@film.Name</p>
}
```

Adjust class and method names accordingly for your project.

Comment: Chris Pratt mentioned this earlier as well, now that it's pointed out it makes sense to do it like that. I'm still learning to work with ASP.NET and MVC as I'm still a student. Thank you for the suggestion.